# How do I create a single file from my HTML form and PHP script so that it is accessed from a pop-up Modal?

Tags: php, html, mysql

The user uploads a file to the server along with details via a html for. The description is then inserted into a MySQL database.

At the moment the process is handled via a html form + a php script.

How do I combine these into a single script, where the description is entered via a Modal form, activated from a button.

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Upload file and add to database</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="comb-insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
      <label for="file">Choose file:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="category">category:</label>
      <input type="text" name="category" id="category">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="title">title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="embedcode">embedcode:</label>
      <input type="text" name="embedcode" id="embedcode">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="video_platform">video_platform:</label>
      <input type="text" name="video_platform" id="video_platform">
    </p>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP script - comb-insert.php**

```
    <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "tabledata");

// Check connection
if ($link === false) {
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['category']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['title']);
$embedcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['embedcode']);
$video_platform = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['video_platform']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_video (category, title, embedcode, video_platform) VALUES ('$category', '$title', '$embedcode', '$video_platform')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
  echo "Records added successfully.<br />";
} else {
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>

// Upload File
<?php
$allowedExts = array("mp3", "mp4");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  } else {
    echo "Din Video er blevet oploaded!!";
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Størrelse: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " findes allerede!. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]
      );
      echo "Gemt i: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question this shall do the thing, if not then please specify what I got wrong so I can edit my answer

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <form action="comb-insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p>
        <label for="file">Choose file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="category">category:</label>
        <input type="text" name="category" id="category">
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="title">title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="embedcode">embedcode:</label>
        <input type="text" name="embedcode" id="embedcode">
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="video_platform">video_platform:</label>
        <input type="text" name="video_platform" id="video_platform">
      </p>


      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

The code for the modal comes from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

I would recommend using AJAX for handling the request since you have a greater control of what happens after submission instead of sending the client to where the form action points